# order by descending bug LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

This is mostly a curiosity rather than a real problem as I've already fixed that bug. I would be glad to have a deep answer that explain the LINQ mechanics behind this wizardry. So I have this query:

```
List<List<IMS_CMM_Measurement>> imsCMMMeasurements = 
    (from i in context.IMS_CMM_Measurement
     where i.Job_FK == jobId 
        && currentOperationCharacteristics.Contains(i.Characteristic_FK)
     select i)
    .GroupBy(elm => elm.Characteristic_FK)
    .Select(CharacGroup => CharacGroup.GroupBy(elm => elm.Part_Number))
    .Select(CharacGroup => CharacGroup.Select(PartGroup => PartGroup.OrderByDescending(measure => measure.Timestamp)))
    .Select(CharacGroup => CharacGroup.Select(PartGroup => PartGroup.FirstOrDefault()))
    .Select(CharacGroup => CharacGroup.OrderBy(measure => measure.Part_Number))
    .Select(CharacGroup => CharacGroup.ToList()).ToList();
```

Basically, it takes measurements from a database and group them by characteristics. For each characteristic there are several measures that correspond to different parts, and some parts are measured more than once. In the later case, we only take the most recent one measure (the one with the greatest Timestamp, wich is a Date format entry). In order to do that, I have to order the measure for each part by the timestamp in decreasing order. Unfortunately, this does the exact opposite: it takes the oldest measure.

I managed to get the appropriate result by doing this instead (adding .ToList() at the end of the LINQ query at the 4th line):

```
List<List<IMS_CMM_Measurement>> imsCMMMeasurements = 
    (from i in context.IMS_CMM_Measurement
     where i.Job_FK == jobId 
        && currentOperationCharacteristics.Contains(i.Characteristic_FK)
     select i).ToList()
    .GroupBy(elm => elm.Characteristic_FK)
    .Select(CharacGroup => CharacGroup.GroupBy(elm => elm.Part_Number))
    .Select(CharacGroup => CharacGroup.Select(PartGroup => PartGroup.OrderByDescending(measure => measure.Timestamp)))
    .Select(CharacGroup => CharacGroup.Select(PartGroup => PartGroup.FirstOrDefault()))
    .Select(CharacGroup => CharacGroup.OrderBy(measure => measure.Part_Number))
    .Select(CharacGroup => CharacGroup.ToList()).ToList();
```

Why does this work now? ;)

Comment: You've basically changed from everything after `ToList` being executed in the database (as the expression was translated to SQL) to doing it all in memory. It's not clear why the database returned the wrong sort order, however.

Comment: Without the `ToList` the entire thing is translated into SQL and run on the DB.  With the `ToList` only the part before it is translated to SQL and the rest is done in code.  Also instead of `ToList` you should use `AsEnumerable` when you want to transfer from a SQL Linq provider to Linq to Objects as it will avoid creating an unneeded intermediate list.

Comment: That's a pretty convoluted and non-standard way to write that query. Although it should technically work, I imagine the linq expression to sql statement translator is making a mistake somewhere due to the odd way this is written.

Comment: How would you have done it instead ? Decompose it in multiple sub-query?